# Cannot install PyAudio using pip. Cannot install PyAudio file through web. Kindle/Fire OS Work around?

Tags: android, python-3.x, python-3.7, pyaudio, kindle

I normally use a windows device and have everything installed properly there. Went to download pydroid 3 on android tablet, got that and pip and all dependencies downloaded besides PyAudio. It seems the .whl file is only compatible with Windows currently.

Is there a workaround to get SpeechRecognition and PyAudio working on android devices? I have the SDK installed for Google Play Store etc..I have installed Pydroid 3 which is running Python 3.7.2. I have tried to roll back to Python 3.6.1 because I guess the wheel is included with that but to no avail so far.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
raise AttributeError( Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
Filedacalatarunic:Pydroilsrtnes/arm-linux
Program finished
```

I expected it to work. Even though it is android based I figured it would still have some SDK or file that could be a workaround. If I can't get PyAudio to work on the Kindle Fire HD10 then I won't be able to get SpeechRecognition to work either. And if neither of those work I will not be able to communicate with my program at all.

Comment: I couldn't get the output of code onto this machine to paste it. I took a picture then used google keep to grab the text from the picture. This is full code output with errors.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/speech recognition/_init-py, line 108, in get pyaudio
import pyaudio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'

Comment: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp files/iiec run/iiec run.py", line 31. in <module»
start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
File "Idata/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
exec(open(mainpyfile).read(). main._dict__)
File "<string?", line 327, in <module>
"<string", line 34, in myCommand
File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/speech recognition/_init py. line 79. in init

Comment: self.pyaudio_module self.get_pyaudio()
File Idata/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/speech recognition/_init -py". line 110. in get pyaudio
raise AttributeError( Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
Filedacalatarunic:Pydroilsrtnes/arm-linux
Program finished